# Bootstrap Select Option

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

im working on simple form, but I'm get stuck in select options. 
Here is my code:

```
<select title="Pick a number" class="selectpicker">
  <option>Select...</option>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

I wanted width of option list is should be equal to select at any screen size. 
How can i achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged bootstrap use it like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
    <select title="Pick a number" class="form-control selectpicker" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option>Select...</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
        <option>Three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Bootstrap ensures that inputs are displayed properly. Have a look [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls) for more informations.